# Eclipselink & Spring Data

Tags: eclipselink, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to implement a solution using a combination of eclipselink (2.4.0) and spring-data-jpa (1.1.0.RELEASE).  However, every time I deploy the solution (Tomcat 7), I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No [ManagedType] was found for 
the key class [com.acme.domain.entities.User] in the Metamodel - please 
verify that the [Managed] class was referenced in persistence.xml using a 
specific <class>com.acme.domain.entities.User</class> property or a global 
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes> element.
```

It appears to occur when the repository autowiring takes place (code examples below):

Service class

```
@Component
public class UserDataService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    ...
}
```

Entity class

```
package com.acme.domain.entities;

...

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Integer id;

    ...

}
```

persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="default" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>    
    <class>com.acme.domain.entities.User</class>

    ...
</persistence-unit>
```

Can this be due to some conflict between spring and eclipselink?

**UPDATE:**

Stacktrace...

```
[#|2012-07-31 16:25:02,317|ERROR|pool-2-thread-40|org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader|Context initialization failed|#]
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDataService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.acme.data.repositories.UserRepository com.acme.data.services.UserDataService.userRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No [ManagedType] was found for the key class [com.acme.domain.entities.User] in the Metamodel - please verify that the [Managed] class was referenced in persistence.xml using a specific <class>com.acme.domain.entities.User</class> property or a global <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes> element.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:609)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:469)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:897)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:873)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:958)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1599)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.acme.data.repositories.UserRepository com.acme.data.services.UserDataService.userRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No [ManagedType] was found for the key class [com.acme.domain.entities.User] in the Metamodel - please verify that the [Managed] class was referenced in persistence.xml using a specific <class>com.acme.domain.entities.User</class> property or a global <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes> element.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:512)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:92)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No [ManagedType] was found for the key class [com.acme.domain.entities.User] in the Metamodel - please verify that the [Managed] class was referenced in persistence.xml using a specific <class>com.acme.domain.entities.User</class> property or a global <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes> element.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:149)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:102)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1442)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:876)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:818)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:735)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:484)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No [ManagedType] was found for the key class [com.acme.domain.entities.User] in the Metamodel - please verify that the [Managed] class was referenced in persistence.xml using a specific <class>com.acme.domain.entities.User</class> property or a global <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes> element.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.entityEmbeddableManagedTypeNotFound(MetamodelImpl.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:489)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:58)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getMetadata(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:65)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:149)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:87)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:70)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:137)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:125)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:41)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:142)
    ... 37 more
```

Comment: can you include the full stack trace.  Is it only the meta-model or do other things not work?

Comment: I've added the stacktrace above - all works fine as long as I add my own repository implementations, i.e. the eclipselink part of the puzzle is fine. As soon as I add spring-data-jpa to the mix, the above occurs...

Comment: Having this exact same issue in a Standalone Application, any updates?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve my issue but it was another setup as the one above, i just add a few things i stumbled across until i was able to solve it in my SE-Environment:

- Bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=338837 affects EclipseLink Version 2.2.0 and below versions. Mostly happening in Local-Environment (RESOURCE_LOCAL). A EclipseLink version-Upgrade or the following workaround may help:

```xml
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
```

- Having multiple persistence.xml files in classpath (e.g. especially in 3th party JARs) that all define the same persistence-unit-name (above "default" may be very common). Try renaming your persistence-unit-name in this case as a first step
- In case of renaming the persistence-unit-name worked but changing it back to the old value reproduces the problem there is either above mentioned 3th party JAR or old JARs of your own project beeing included to your build (e.g. refactoring/ renaming on project level or similar changed the structure so for example a maven build could still take old build artifacts from the repository)

Finaly when it comes to my setup (Spring-Standalone Application, no persistence.xml but tons of Spring-configurations because a custom company Framework is used) it showed that i just forgot to add the the entity-package of the custom framework-core when i wanted to run one of their service-implementations (Spring-Bean implementation) in my local project rather than having their service-implementation from a JAR-dependency. So make sure that you have all of the required entity packages listed for your EntityManagerFactory:

```xml
    <bean id="customEntityManagerFactory" parent="abstractEntityManagerFactory">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>


        <!-- Packages of EntityClasses -->
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list merge="true">
                <value>ch.company.div1.foo.bar.model</value>
                <value>ch.company.div1.foo.barnicle.model</value>
                <value>ch.company.div2.we.help.model</value>
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props merge="true">
                <prop key="eclipselink.target-database">org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.SQLServerPlatform
                </prop>
                <prop key="javax.persistence.transactionType">RESOURCE_LOCAL</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
     </bean>
```

In my case i forgot to add the model packagege with the used entitys of another division (that writes the custom framework core) of our company.

Good luck, that error's a beast :/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are having the same problem I had: trying to create 2 different entity factories... The exception is the same, so maybe this will help. Essentially this exception was happening when it was instantiating an Entity on the wrong EntityManagerFactory.

My project was running fine with a single database connection but when I added a second one EclipseLink was confused on where to instantiate my entities. After a few debug my conclusion was to remove the property "packagesToScan" from my root-context.xml and replace it with a "persistenceXmlLocation". In that XML, I listed every class I needed to be scanned and excluded everything else with "<exclude-unlisted-classes>"

Here is my full XML configuration that is currently working:

root-context.xml

```
<bean id="dataSource1" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://server1.example.com:5432/db1" />
    <property name="username" value="username" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />
    <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false" />
    <property name="initialSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxIdle" value="5" />
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="600000" />
    <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true" />
    <property name="maxOpenPreparedStatements" value="10" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource2" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://server2.example.com:5432/db2" />
    <property name="username" value="user" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />
    <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false" />
    <property name="initialSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxIdle" value="5" />
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="600000" />
    <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true" />
    <property name="maxOpenPreparedStatements" value="10" />
</bean>


<bean id="emf1" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource1" />
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence1.xml" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="false" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="eclipselink.weaving" value="false" />
            <entry key="eclipselink.logging.level" value="WARNING" />
            <entry key="eclipselink.logging.timestamp" value="false" />
            <entry key="eclipselink.logging.session" value="false" />
            <entry key="eclipselink.logging.thread" value="false" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
        <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="emf2" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource2" />
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence2.xml" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="false" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="eclipselink.weaving" value="false" />
            <entry key="eclipselink.logging.level" value="WARNING" />
            <entry key="eclipselink.logging.timestamp" value="false" />
            <entry key="eclipselink.logging.session" value="false" />
            <entry key="eclipselink.logging.thread" value="false" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
        <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean name="transaction1" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" p:entity-manager-factory-ref="emf1" />
<bean name="transaction2" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" p:entity-manager-factory-ref="emf2" />

<jpa:repositories base-package="org.myproject.repository1" transaction-manager-ref="transaction1" entity-manager-factory-ref="emf1" />
<jpa:repositories base-package="org.myproject.repository2" transaction-manager-ref="transaction2" entity-manager-factory-ref="emf2" />

<tx:annotation-driven />
```

persistence1.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="persistence1" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>org.myproject.repository1.Repo1</class>
    <class>org.myproject.repository1.Repo2</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
</persistence-unit>
```

persistence2.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="persistence2" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>org.myproject.repository2.Repo1</class>
    <class>org.myproject.repository2.Repo2</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
</persistence-unit>
```

So, this works for me...

Apparently specifying each "persistence.xml" location prevents classes that are meant for another EntityManagerFactory to be instantiated on the first "emf". In fact, this looks like a bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=338837. All I could figure out from my debugging is that without the "persistenceXmlLocation" ALL classes that are found with "packageScan" were instantiated on the first created "emf", the second "emf" was completely ignored.

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Add the package (`com.acme.domain.entities`) with entities to `packagesToScan`.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `PersistenceUnitName`, instead of the `persistenceXmlLocation`

No `persistence.xml` needed.

```
factory.setPersistenceUnitName("dummy1");
factory.setPersistenceUnitName("dummy2");
```